# Is repeated exposure to near/mid/far infrared safe for skin and eyes?

Tags: radiation

I've been doing a lot of research into infrared saunas as they've risen in popularity. I've come across a fair amount of information about how harmful near infrared exposure can be to the eyes.

This [study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3116568/) was done on rabbits, and doesn't differentiate between near/mid/far, but concludes that, "The protein of eye lens is very sensitive to IR radiation which is hazardous and may lead to cataract".

This [research](https://ehs.lbl.gov/resource/documents/radiation-protection/non-ionizing-radiation/light-and-infrared-radiation/#:%7E:text=Prolonged%20exposure%20to%20IR%20radiation,eye%2C%20swelling%2C%20or%20hemorrhaging.) published by Berkeley does differentiate between near/mid/far and indicates that near poses the greatest risk to the eye.

> "Near‐Infrared Exposure and Cataracts The most common eye disease
> associated with near-infrared radiation is cataracts. Prolonged
> exposure to IR radiation causes a gradual but irreversible opacity of
> the lens. Other forms of damage to the eye from IR exposure include
> scotoma, which is a loss of vision due to the damage to the retina.
> Even low-level IR absorption can cause symptoms such as redness of the
> eye, swelling, or hemorrhaging.
>
> Cataracts caused by near‐infrared radiation have been noted
> historically in glassblowers and furnace workers. Radiation between
> 800 and 1,200 nm is most likely responsible for temperature increases
> in the lens itself because of its spectral‐absorption characteristics.
> Visible wavelengths may also contribute to the problem, since the heat
> absorbed by the iris could result in heat transfer to the lens.
>
> Acute Skin, Cornea, and Iris Injury IR radiation below 3,000 nm will
> penetrate into different depths of the cornea to varying degrees,
> depending on the specific wavelength. The iris can absorb energy only
> at wavelengths below approximately 1,300 nm.
>
> IR thermal injury may have significant biological effects on the human
> skin. The IR-A rays induce free radicals in the dermis and diminish
> the skin’s antioxidant capacity, the main cause of premature skin
> aging.
>
> Both the skin and the cornea are opaque to wavelengths >1,400 nm.
> Exposure to IR radiation in this region causes injury through thermal
> mechanisms, with absorbed radiation being converted to heat."

But, it's hard to understand if this would translate to consistent usage of saunas that leverage near/mid/far infrared. In the case of the Berkeley research, it's looking mostly at workplace hazards (welding, etc.), which in many cases would require participants to have their eyes open and very close to the heat source. But if the issue is simply that infrared heat is penetrating and heating the cornea, it would seem that that could be an issue for saunas as well. It also seems to indicate that even far infrared would be damaging to the skin, when sauna companies are claiming the exact opposite to be true.

I find it quite alarming that sauna companies are [touting near infrared as a "plus"](https://www.sunlighten.com/light-science/what-is-infrared-light/) when it sounds like most research points to it being harmful in the long run.

My question is this: does anyone know if far infrared is conclusively safe for the eyes and skin in repeated use in something like a sauna? Is near infrared really the risk? Or is how saunas are using it below some threshold of safety?

Comment: It would depend strongly on the intensity of the source. The cataracts for furnace/glassblowers are from high intensity sources in relatively close proximity - close enough to get splashed with liquid metal according to the historical documents.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_dose_makes_the_poison

Comment: Forgot to add, our eyes are *always* exposed to IR while we are alive - our bodies are warm after all, and IR is the "heat" wavelengths of radiation. There is also ambient heat wherever we are.